# Changing global-whitespace-mode options locally to a particular buffer

Tags: hooks, whitespace-mode

I want to customize the behavior of global-whitespace-mode on a per-major-mode basis, and also define some interactive commands that change what's being highlighted on a per-buffer basis.  global-whitespace-mode does something rather more complicated than just turning on whitespace-mode in every buffer, I don't particularly understand why, but anyway it's getting in the way of me writing those interactive commands.  Specifically, this function works as a mode hook but not as an interactive command:

```
(defun turn-off-highlight-long-lines ()
  "Turn off highlighting of long lines via global-whitespace-mode."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((already-active-p (local-variable-p 'whitespace-active-style))
         (desired-style
          (delq 'lines (copy-sequence (if already-active-p
                                          whitespace-active-style
                                        whitespace-style)))))
    (if already-active-p
        (progn (setq whitespace-active-style desired-style)
               (whitespace-color-on))
      (setq-local whitespace-style desired-style))))
```

But this seems to be exactly what `(global-)whitespace-toggle-options` does, except buffer-locally, so I'm stumped.

(I'm not using `(global-)whitespace-toggle-options` because I want the effect to be buffer-local.)

Comment: `M-x whitespace-toggle-options` is buffer-local for me; what was making you think it wasn't? I often do `M-x whitespace-toggle-options L` to turn off long line visualization in a specific buffer.

Comment: It's possible that I misunderstood the code and/or tested it wrong, but it sure seems like  `M-x whitespace-toggle-options` *globally* changes the options for *local* whitespace-mode, and therefore both has no effect because I'm only using global-whitespace-mode, and wouldn't do what I want anyway.

Comment: Ah, I'm sure it's my fault: turns out I don't use global-whitespace-mode. Personally I enable whitespace-mode early in my config, then in certain mode hooks (like in `go-mode-hook`), I do a `(whitespace-toggle-options '(lines-tail)`. That doesn't answer your question but hopefully it helps give some ideas!